# How to avoid repetition of conditions in EXISTS clause in a UNION

Tags: sql, db2

I have this `SQL` in `DB2` and want to avoid repeating the conditions in the `EXISTS` clause in the second `UNION`, as the conditions can be fairly large. How do I do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
select id from table t where t.given_name = 'good' and t.time = 1 and exists
    (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.surname = 'OK') union
select id from table t where t.given_name = 'good' and t.time = 2 and not exists
    (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.surname = 'OK')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `union`?  How about just doing this?

```
select id
from table t
where t.given_name = 'good' and
      t.time in (1, 2) and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.surname = 'OK');
```

If `id` could have duplicates, use `select distinct` in the outer query.'

EDIT:

I think I misread the original query.  The logic would be:

```
select id
from table t
where t.given_name = 'good' and
      ( (t.time = 1 and exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.surname = 'OK')
        ) or
        (t.time = 2 and not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.surname = 'OK')
        )
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Gordon.

Comment: I use union because the ids I want to have are two separate group ids with one group satifying exists condition and another satifying not exists condition. The first select is filtered by t.time - 1 and the second by t.time = 2.

Comment: `surname` should reference from the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be also achieve via `where` clause only

```
where given_name = 'good' and 
     (times = 1 and surname = 'OK') or 
     (times = 2 and surname <> 'OK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a WITH clause to remove redundancy

```
with t2 as (select * from t1 where surname = 'OK')
select id from table t where t.given_name = 'good' and t.time = 1 and exists
    (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id) union
select id from table t where t.given_name = 'good' and t.time = 2 and not exists
    (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id) 
;
```

and you can do the same for the other table too if needed

```
with t2 as (select * from t1 where surname = 'OK')
,    tt as (select * from t  where given_name = 'good')
select id from table tt where tt.time = 1 and exists
    (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = tt.id) union
select id from table tt where tt.time = 2 and not exists
    (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = tt.id) 
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot P.Vernon. I found out the With clause after I posted the question. It is what I was looking for to get rid of redundancy.
Cheers,
Rodge